# BASH: if line matches - delete line + next 33 lines

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a file full of records ...each record is 34 lines long.

I need to purge this file of any record where the first line of record matches a string.
This first line is a location code. File must be purged of all records from a certain location. There is a blank line after the first line in each record ...actually several, however, any occurrence of a blank line would indicate that this record belongs to this location.

So --

if line matches
and next line is blank
then delete line + 33 lines after the line.

Would prefer a bash solution as that is what I'm most familiar with, but perl is OK.

Some have asked for sample ( this record is 34 lines in real life ):

```
LOCATION



DARRYL MITHRANDIR
5 LONGBOTTOM LEAF LN
HOBBITON, ME  99999

We rang to notify you that we have the following items:

1 blade - glamdring = $1,000
1 shrunken troll head = $1

Available for pick-up at the following location:

LOCATION
8 SMAUG LN
MORDOR, ME  99998
```

As you can see, the location always occurs as the first line in the record followed by a series of blank lines. It occurs elsewhere in the record, but always followed by a line of text indicating street address.

Comment: Does `line + 33 lines` contain `several blank lines`?

Comment: Some sample input would be beneficial. We are sort of flying blind without it.

Comment: Hope the sample text will help. These records are 34 lines long and catenated together in a single massive file.

Comment: @sarnold. I am able to match the line with any number of tools: sed, grep ...etc. But hit a wall at the deletion part. Maybe there is a better way to think about this than what I've suggested?

Comment: @Bubnoff yes it did. I just updated my answer using your example to show that it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is an answer with `awk`.  Change `LOCATION` to whatever regex suits your needs as your match.

```
  awk '/LOCATION/{l=$0;getline;if(!$0)i=33; else print l}i{if(--i);next}1'
```

#### Example based off yours

```
$ cat ./input
LOCATION  ### DELETE THIS RECORD ###



DARRYL MITHRANDIR
5 LONGBOTTOM LEAF LN
HOBBITON, ME  99999

We rang to notify you that we have the following items:

1 blade - glamdring = $1,000
1 shrunken troll head = $1

Available for pick-up at the following location:

CHUCKS AMAZING BARGAINS
8 SMAUG LN
MORDOR, ME  99998
LOCATION  ### DONT DELETE THIS RECORD, NEXT LINE NOT BLANK ###
FOO BAR
31337 EXAMPLE WAY
EXAMPLETON, EX  12345

We rang to notify you that we have the following items:

1 ring of awkfu = $99,000,000
1 troll face = jelly?

Available for pick-up at the following location:

SIEGEXS AMAZING EXAMPLES
314159 PI CIRCLE
NOWHERE, NA 00000
```

#### Output with your 17-line/record example

```
$ awk '/LOCATION/{l=$0;getline;if(!$0)i=17; else print l}i{if(--i);next}1' ./input
LOCATION  ### DONT DELETE THIS RECORD, NEXT LINE NOT BLANK ###
FOO BAR
31337 EXAMPLE WAY
EXAMPLETON, EX  12345

We rang to notify you that we have the following items:

1 ring of awkfu = $99,000,000
1 troll face = jelly?

Available for pick-up at the following location:

SIEGEXS AMAZING EXAMPLES
314159 PI CIRCLE
NOWHERE, NA 00000
```

Comment: Shouldn't we check if the next line after matching pattern is blank? That is his prerequisite … `if line matches pattern and next line is blank, delete 33 lines`.

Comment: What about `MATCH\n\n\n`? Note: `...actually several` in the question.

Comment: @kev He just added that.  However, in either case, my script still works as he only cares about the next line being blank to initiate the deletion of the next 33 lines.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I was trying stuff with sed and offloading stuff to temp files. This looks much nicer.

Comment: `1 troll face = jelly?` LOL .. This is indeed `SIEGEXS AMAZING EXAMPLES`. :-)

Comment: @SiegX. Works dude. You rock!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '/LOCATION/{N;/\n$/{:a;N;x;s/^/X/;/^X\{32\}/{g;d};x;ba}}' file
```

As per instructions:

> if line matches and next line is blank then delete line + 33 lines after the line.

Explanation:

- (1) Match on `LOCATION`
- If (1) above

  - append next line `N`
  - (2) Match last character of the pattern space (PS) to being a newline i.e. an empty line.

    - if (2) above

      - create a label `:a`
      - append a newline then the next line to the (PS) `N`
      - swap the PS with the hold space (HS another register) `x`
      - append an `X` to the front of the HS `s/^/X/`
      - (3) Match the HS with 32 `X`'s `/^X\{32\}/`

        - If (3) above

          - copy the PS over the HS `g`
          - delete the HS and start next cycle `d`
        - else

          - swap from HS back to PS `x`
          - goto label `ba`

Comment: I understand the first part of your command ...match, get next line, check if blank .....??? It's a beauty, and works ...but I'm failing to grasp how it works. Thank you for this submission to my problem!

Comment: @Bubnoff I'll edit the answer to give an explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with `awk` -

```
awk '/YOUR PATTERN/ {
i=$0;getline; if($0~/^$/)
for(i=1;i<34;i++) {getline} else {print i,$0;next}}1' file
```

#### Explanation:

1. We look for the lines containing your pattern.
2. If we find it, we store the entire line in variable `i`.
3. We then inspect the next line by using `getline` keyword, if it is a `blank line` we move down 33 times.
4. If the next line is not a blank line, we print out variable `i`.
5. The `1` at the very end is for printing all lines that do not match the pattern.